# REGEX - Only accept boundary value if it isn't preceded by a certain character?

Tags: regex, perl

How do I make it so the regex only considers the boundary to be valid if it isn't preceded by a certain character?

For example if the boundary is a bracket and I don't want it to consider any bracket characters preceded by an exclamation mark as valid, how would I do it?

Example:

```
(Comp!)uter)
```

The !) should be ignored and it should capture the entire string

I've tried

```
\(.+?[^\!]\)
```

and

```
\(.+?(?!\!)\)
```

However they both don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\(.+?[^\!]\)` does work for the example you gave.

```
$ perl -E'say "(Comp!)uter)" =~ /\( .+? [^!] \)/xs ? $& : "no match"'
(Comp!)uter)
```

This approach won't match `()`, though.

---

`\(.+?(?!\!)\)` is close. You want to look behind, the `)`, so you need to use `(?<! ... )`.

```
$ perl -E'say "(Comp!)uter)" =~ /\( .+? (?<! ! )\)/xs ? $& : "no match"'
(Comp!)uter)
```

---

Look arounds are a little expensive, and using the `?` non-greedy modifier for anything but optimization can easily cause problems. I'd use the following, which also matches `()`:

```
/\( (?: !. | [^!)]+ )* \)/sx
```

But you always want to be wary of unnecessary backtracking. This performs very badly if the ending `)` is missing, which can be fixed as follows:

```
/\( (?: !. | [^!)]++ )*+ \)/sx
```

Comment: Yes, but if you don't use an atomic group, this may cause a catastrophic backtracking if the closing parenthesis doesn't exist.

Comment: Backtracking issue fixed.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for teaching me something new again.  [`++`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Possessive-quantifiers) as a special case of the [`independent subexpression`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-independent-subexpressions-to-prevent-backtracking).  I kinda wish the docs mentioned that special case in the subexpression docs, I might've learned about it sooner.  +1

Comment: @ikegami The OP's specification is unclear, but it's possible that a bang should not escape itself.  If that's the case, then the regex should be modified to `/\( (?: !++. | [^!)]++ )*+ \)/sx`

Comment: @Miller, `(?:PAT)?+`, `(?:PAT)*+` and `(?:PAT)++` can also be written as `(?>(?:PAT)?)`, `(?>(?:PAT)*)` and `(?>(?:PAT)+)`, which is more backwards-compatible.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, that's how I've always written it since perl 5.8?  Just found it curious that the docs for independent subexpressions don't mention the possessive quantifiers special case.  Fortunately, the reverse is true `These possessive quantifiers represent a special case of a more general concept, the independent subexpression`.

Comment: @Miller, Documentation patches accepted. Submit them using `perlbug`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a group with a negated character class and an alternation:

```
(?s)\((?>[^!)]+|!.)*\)
```

*Note that if your string contains newlines after the `!` character, you should use the s modifier.*

Comment: If it doesn't contain newlines, then `s` won't change anything, so you might as well use `s` to make the pattern more efficient!

Comment: Indeed, why not put it directly!

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want to capture what's inside parenthesis, the closing parenthesis being "escaped" if there is a `!` before it?

You could use something like

```
\([^)!]+(?:!.[^)!]*)*\)

\(          # opening parenthesis
[^)!]+      # anything but a closing parenthesis or a !
(?:         # non capturing group
    !.     # a ! followed by anything
    [^)!]*  # anything but a closing parenthesis or a !
)*          # capturing group pattern zero or more times
\)          # closing parenthesis
```

The idea behind is:

- after the first `(`, we match everything which is not a `)` or `!` with `[^)!]+`
- when this stops, either there is a `!`, if so we match the following character with `!.` and we repeat the `[^)!]+`
- or we have an unescaped `)` and we close the match

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture `Comp` of it it's followed by `uter` then `Computer, you should try something like this:

```
(Comp(?:uter)?)
```

The `?:` makes the second parenthesis non capturing so it won't mess up your capture group references.

If you want to capture `Comp` in case of it's folowed by `uter` then you need a positive look ahead:

```
(Comp(?=uter))
```

The `?=` will do a zero-width assertion by looking at the following text. (See `?!` for negative look-ahead, and `?<=` and `?<!` for positive and negative look-behinds)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the exclamation point to negate only brackets, this should work

```
(?<=\()([a-zA-Z](!\))?)+(?=\))
```